# Python Detect Audio by Microphone

Tags: python, audio

I just want to detect audio in Python and stop my Microphone. Any easy ways to do it? I have tried pyaudio but, it is complex and want to do a project quickly. Either way it only records audio but is not used for on the fly detection. So, please provide other modules which can be used.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what do you exactly want ?

Comment: I want to make a bot which detects sound and mutes mic. When we stop speaking it opens back mic. The only thing im stuck at is the active detection of sound.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `sounddevice` package. By starting an [`InputStream`](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.15/api/streams.html#sounddevice.InputStream) and monitoring the incoming buffer levels, you could perhaps achieve the stated goal.

In this approach, the mic is always 'on', but you're only capturing the data when
there is no speech.

A skeleton example below

```
import sounddevice as sd
import Queue

buffer_size = 4410 # 100 ms worth of samples at 44.1 kHz 
mic_stream = sd.InputStream(blocksize=buffer_size) # also need to specify samplerate and device etc.


recording_condition = True # a variable that defines when the recording should be stopped

mic_stream.start() # start the InputStream

audio_queue = Queue.Queue()


while recording_condition:
    audio_buffer, success = mic_stream.read(buffer_size)
    # here use your speech detection algorithm 
    speech_in_buffer = your_speech_detector(audio_buffer)
    if not speech_in_buffer:
        audio_queue.put(audio_buffer)
```

Once the `recording_condition` becomes False, you can then get all the audio buffers in the queue with

```
all_audio_buffer = [ audio_queue.get()[0] for i in range(self.audio_queue.qsize()) ]
```